# SQL SELECT WHERE with date and time

Tags: mysql, select

I have a `SELECT` query where I want to find all rows whose DATE and TIME are between `2011-12-11 23:00:00` and  `2011-12-12 23:00:00` I try to do it with WHERE but row is empty

```
WHERE (date >= '2011-12-11' AND time > '23:00:00' )
AND   (date <  '2011-12-12' AND time < '23:00:00' )
```

Pls, any good suggestion how to change this?

Comment: you should post the complete query

Comment: problem is with WHERE, the rest of the query is ok => SELECT * FROM abc WHERE .... the Left side of WHERE and the right side works separately ok. But together no.

Comment: or maybe something with BETWEEN but I dont know how to write it correctly.

Comment: @Andrew - I gave you a solution with BETWEEN 10 minutes before you posted this. can you explain the significance of the time field? Do you actually store date and time in separate fields? If so, a database overhaul is needed

Comment: Sure would be nice if the where clause didn't have typos in it.

Comment: @Andrew - try my new edit. Not sure it will work but based on how you have things set up (i STILL highly suggest you fix this) it may work

Comment: @JM$ ups - its a wrong information :((, yes, of course, DATE and TIME in separate fields, as I simply wrote

Comment: @Andrew - what do you mean 'its a wrong information'? The parameters in your query make results impossible. Please read and try values that work. Right now you are saying "I am looking for results where the date is after 11PM on December 11, 2012 but before 11 PM December 13, 2011.

Comment: @JM4 - I see what you were referring to. I just edited it so that the `WHERE` clause matches the original question.

Answer (score 11):

You could use:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATETIME(date) BETWEEN '2011-11-11 23:00:00' AND '2011-12-13 23:00:00'
```

or separate:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATETIME(date) > '2011-12-11 23:00:00' AND DATETIME(date) < '2011-12-13 23:00:00'
```

### EDIT:

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here or how your DB is laid out but assuming date and time are separate fields:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATETIME(concat(DATE(date),' ',TIME(time))) BETWEEN '2011-11-11 23:00:00' AND '2011-12-13 23:00:00'
```

I haven't tested but this may work.

Comment: thanks for your help but, as I wrote, I use DATE and TIME, no DATESTAMP

Comment: @Andrew - then unless I am not understanding the significance of your two fields, this is poor DB design. Please explain what the date and time fields represent

Comment: I'm really thinking about connection this two fields into one. Thnks.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, that's pretty much not going to work.  Show me all rows where time is greater than 11 pm and time is less that 11 pm.  Time and Date are different fields?

You'll have to be a little more clever building up the query:

```
WHERE  (date = '2011-12-11' AND  time > '23:00:00' )
  or  ( date = '2011-12-12' AND time < '23:00:00' )
```

for a 24 hour window, you just need to have 2 clauses.  If you want more than a 24 hour window, you'll need three clauses, one for the start date, one for the end date and one for all the dates in between:

```
WHERE  (date = '2011-12-11' AND  time > '23:00:00' )
  or  ( date = '2011-12-13' AND time < '23:00:00' )
  or (date >='2011-12-12' and date  < '2011-12-13')
```

Comment: That was because your initial query had the wrong dates.  Try it now.

Comment: thnks, it is working ok (as I think) but can you rebuild something? First I wrote a wrong date - 2011-11-11. The good date is 2011-12-11. It must be only 24hours interval between the dates. IN your WHERE I change all 2011-11-11 to 2011-12-11, it is working but i dont kwnow is it ok or not?

Comment: Andrew, so you want all records between November 11, 2011 at 11pm and November 12, 2011 at 11pm?  You DO know that the standard date format for MySQL is yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Yes I want, Yes I know. The problem is with f.ex. event at 11 pm and website user with Time zone (+ 1H). I must display the event with UTC 2011-12-11 23:05:00 as f.ex. Berlin Time 2011-12-12 01:05:00.

Answer (score 2):

ha, and I have the solution without rebuild the dbase - it's working :))

```
WHERE 
CONCAT(date,' ',time) >= '2011-12-11 23:00:00' 
AND   
CONCAT(date,' ',time) <  '2011-12-12 23:00:00'
```

Maybe it helps for someone.

thanks for all helping people, brgs

Comment: Very nice solution.  But don't forget that this will trigger a full table scan if it's the only criteria that you are using.

Comment: @BrianHoover - sorry, didn't mean to come across as rude - just didn't understand how the question owner 'came up' with his own answer when the same one is listed above

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell without the complete query.  also assuming that the date column is actually a date type(?) you would usually do something like `TO_DATE('2012-12-11','yyyy-mm-dd')` to convert to date types in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make sure of certain things

- You need to get rid of the idea of separate `date` and `time` fields when searching
- You need to create an additional column in your table called `date_time` (type DATETIME) which combines the two fields.
- You should probably ditch the separate `date` and `time` fields and have just `date_time`
- You can then create an index on `date_time`

Here is the command to do that

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD INDEX date_time (date_time);
```

Once you do these things, THEN you can create a query with a WHERE clause that looks like this:

```
WHERE date_time >= '2011-12-11 23:00:00'
AND   date_time <  '2011-12-12 23:00:00'
```

**If you cannot combine the date and time fields**, you can still create an index

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD INDEX date_time (date,time);
```

Given that situation, you can create a query with a WHERE clause that looks like this:

```
WHERE (date >= '2011-12-11' AND time >= '23:00:00')
AND   (date <= '2011-12-12' AND time <  '23:00:00')
```

The EXPLAIN plan for either situation should result in a fast execution of the query with the use of the date_time index.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I must to write - you present it as a teacher. May everyone have such skills. Thank you very much, certainly test. It's a little bit higher ride but definitely worth knowing.

Comment: I do the index - generaly it ordered the displayed date. Its ok. But hits are Zero, nothing, null. At this moment the WHERE structure by @Brian Hoover only working ok.